# Restore ZFS Pool after a broken HDD

Tags: zfs, restore, hdd

i lost my ZFS Pool on a trueNAS System due to a failed / broken disk

The Pool was a non mirrored Pool with 4 HDD (6-10 TB each)
I am working on a new trueNAS for backup all the files to a mirrored pool (more safety, etc...)
yes... a bit late, why i didn't do that to my first trueNAS... so as a student project i just took some HDD, bring that to a trueNAS Pool and wow, a lot of storage (and no safety, i know now)
the last years a lot of data was stored, and yes, a small peace like some documents and configs, i have no backup.
so my new NAS is ready but i cannot rsync the data from the broken pool.

now my qustion, is it possible to restore some of the data, even when 1 HDD is broken ? 
 zpool status dont list my Stripe1 Pool,

```
zpool import:
   pool: Stripe1
     id: 6025154047609482622
  state: UNAVAIL
status: One or more devices are missing from the system.
 action: The pool cannot be imported. Attach the missing
        devices and try again.
   see: https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/msg/ZFS-8000-3C
 config:
        Stripe1                                       UNAVAIL  insufficient replicas
          gptid/c1b3f4e5-d0c3-11e9-bb74-bcaec56636cd  ONLINE
          gptid/c2313d8f-d0c3-11e9-bb74-bcaec56636cd  UNAVAIL  cannot open
          gptid/907c5655-8970-11ec-b041-40167e36fb5f  ONLINE
          gptid/9f932a06-8657-11ec-9301-40167e36fb5f  ONLINE
```

i have a new 10 TB drive aroung (the unavailable one)

is there a way (except running testdisk over month) to get some of the data back ?

best regards
daniel